# Why does selenium not work on my browsers?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to automate through python using selenium and I need help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

Sergo=['Sergo']
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
print(driver.title)
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')
search.send_keys(Sergo)


time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/user/Desktop/bot/automation.py", line 11, in <module>
    search.send_keys(Sergo)

  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,

  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)

  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response

    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath is not unique

[image]

Use this xpath:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id='search']')
```

Comment: welcome, xndrem))

Comment: mekel mi bane harcnem? unique xpath vonces gtnum?

Comment: shat shat mersi

Comment: anpayman! norek em es volortum!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have the Chromedriver.

- Click on the 3 dots at the right-top in your Chrome browser
- Click on About Chrome/Chromium
- Check the version mentioned in light gray
- Go to the ChromeDriver [downloads page]
  (https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).
- Download the correct version as per your browser version.
- Copy the path to ChromeDriver.exe
- As an argument,pass `executable_path=r'path/to/chromedriver.exe'`
  in `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`.
- For example, mine is:

  `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\dell\Libs\chromedriver.exe')`